# Can we use MySql8Dialect in hibernate 4.1.10 FINAL?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to connect to MySql 8.0 DB form my maven application. But I found MySql8Dialect is only available in Hibernate 5.3.1.Final + versions. When I go to update my existing hibernate version from 4.1.10 to 5.3.1, I have to upgrade java also as hibernate 5.3.1 needs at least Java 1.8.

This is a big mess for me as I can't go for java upgrade from existing 1.7  right now because of some constraints.

Is there a way to use MySql8Dialect in Hibernate 4.1.10.Final ?

Comment: Do you actually have a problem that you **need** that dialect. I think that likely MySQL 8 will work just fine if you use a Hibernate dialect for a lower MySQL version, you might just miss some new features or types. In any case, you probably can't just use the dialect of a newer Hibernate version because of API evolution.

Comment: @Mark  Hibernate-core 4.1.10.FINAL jar has only Mysql5Dialect.class inside it which is specific to mysql 5.x. When I try to use the same with  mysql8.0 db, it gives me an error while running the application that the queries generated are not correct.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to 4.3.x instead (and using MySQL57InnoDBDialect) if going to 5.x is too much effort right now? In any case, consider rephrasing your question in the terms of your problem (the error) and your constraints (not being able to upgrade to Java 8 or higher), instead of asking us if you can just use a class from a totally different version.